# How to search string in nested object and update the property for all child and parent

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array of objects in the hierarchical data structure. I need to check if any of the parents or children nodes contains a search string. I am able to filter the array, but I just want to update the **matchFound** property instead of applying the filter on the tree data.

Expected Result:
If match is found, **matchFound** property of all the parent and children nodes should be true otherwise false.

```js
treeData = [{
    name: 'Infiniti',
    matchFound: null,
    children: [{
        name: 'G50',
        matchFound: null,
        children: [{
            name: 'Pure AWD',
            matchFound: null,
          },
          {
            name: 'Luxe',
            matchFound: null,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: 'QX50',
        matchFound: null,
        children: [{
            name: 'Pure AWD',
            matchFound: null,
          },
          {
            name: 'Luxe',
            matchFound: null,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    name: 'BMW',
    matchFound: null,
    children: [{
        name: '2 Series',
        matchFound: null,
        children: [{
            name: 'Coupé',
            matchFound: null,
          },

          {
            name: 'Gran Coupé',
            matchFound: null,
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        name: '3 Series',
        matchFound: null,

        children: [{
            name: 'Sedan',
            matchFound: null,
          },
          {
            name: 'PHEV',
            matchFound: null,
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];

filteredData = [];

function filter(searchString) {
  this.filteredData = this.search(this.treeData, searchString);
  console.log(this.filteredData)
}

function search(children, searchString) {
  return children.reduce((acc, item) => {
    if (item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchString.toLowerCase())) {
      acc.push(item);
    } else if (item.children && item.children.length > 0) {
      const newItems = this.search(item.children, searchString);
      if (newItems.length > 0) {
        acc.push({
          name: item.name,
          children: newItems
        });
      }
    }

    return acc;
  }, []);
}

this.filter('infiniti');
this.filter('luxe');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can propose a solution wiht some assumptions:

1. The filter method should return new tree structure, and should not modify the original one
2. If any of the child nodes has match - all the parents are marked as matchFound=true

Here is a [working playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMJygOQPYBMUDeAUMqSHALYQBcyAzmFKAOYDcJpFcYCAFgGLYAriFy0ARtmwAbCHBDIAPshBDp09qWR9g03FAggA-LQCCUKHACeAHnRY8EAHzsAvkSIJsIBskYQIABFuODMLazsMHHwnZABeZABtYi0VShpkAHIASRAYUGAwYEyAGg5Obj5BETEVNWky1J09AxBaZPLUtKpaTIBxAFYABlLO1K4eAWFRWlV1Rq7SZv1DdpTFrvIerIAFIQNkUwB1QNGNromq6dq5hrGu1wXz9fOydN6AGSEADwgz14qk2qMzq83uqUe4OQAF0nlpIYsXpt3lkAIoADWG-0WlymNVm9ThTV4uhWbSSSPOWwymT2B2OpyJG1xwJuhKhpARr0pG2pnx%20fyZOMqeJBtyF8IlsPuXNI0s5CyRfKyACEALJHbHIFnXAlg4mk1prKHKzIAJmQAGVoMAIHQteMRay9XdzssjRSOVpTahhAAHACXDuZTt1oNdr0hXp5i1NfUsCl9QkDweFQLD4q9sq68oeTJj3RpAGYrTa7antaH8eGylD3atPQC3ttMtbcPIK4709XMwDs4ivc2aTsABIAUQAap2tDqe%20y%201Kmdnc5DoewPDARAgit5kPlpJAoAAKOhyKB8S2MFi0BhMEDMACUyHWBjA%20wU-iCIQAdFw-UeQEceJYlPDA%20AAxwSnoM8Lyve8HwfVhkCIdwiE3EBt2AXdQPPXgIPwWh7GiCAoJw2C72YG84OYKCYGuXIdgwQwwHiPc4GkU8H0IqIgOIDgvB8FjZ1EXJiIAeSgRjWhYhI6JqBimPAJRlEA-Bv2pb8wGwD5sAAd2gdBTyPB9v1ABBpCEfA6BPGDeEvCjNO0vSDLgIyEPXJZvF8esFASVSICMb8fMCv8j2WYDoLAvDllI2z7JYZASmE3BRMcCSpOY9yPFIAB6HLcWQYA6D3a5CpgZA-UUljsCgPwSWK-zkBq5BuGQWRXOqkAUGwcqwF4bQSRaQxkF4VzKz6hASpqfivKEqtRFY5LUvwdKquU5AjwGw1hoAQjiBIaggfIutwZAADIzq2oaQG-OhsCoMLBtOuJYmWX95twLKODy193xUCBdKa8QACsIG3DhfqgBQfOQPaDtEI7QAgU6jGfZBvwx-yoOSqCYdcZBaAIdHMcg8arhqZBXDcDwBN8UBjsKKwACU7TUGTSH3Q8j0yemCiKTJEM8Wa2oFFm6DZ1jOegbmLN%20AX11pmQIG-aRsGYI8ACJeZARmxbZjWSm13XWYPQXFdkFW1c12WID1g8DZF347bARCgA)

And I'll paste the meaningful parts of the code:

```js
function filter(searchString: string) {
  return treeData.map(node => search(node, searchString)); 
}

function search(node: CarNode, searchString: string, foundInParent = false): CarNode {
  const matchFoundInNodeOrParent = foundInParent || node.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchString.toLowerCase());

  const children = node?.children?.map(child => search(child, searchString ,matchFoundInNodeOrParent));

  //match is found if parent or this node or at least one of th children has mathc found
  const matchFound = matchFoundInNodeOrParent || ( children !== undefined && children.some(child => child.matchFound));

  //return new object
  return children !== undefined ? { ...node, matchFound, children } : { ...node, matchFound };
}
```